# Django, extending the User model, ImportError: cannot import name User

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I read that this has to do with a **circular dependency** but I really couldn't found a workaround. I'm trying to get the number of Users(that belong to an organization) and maybe some more details related to Users but it seems that I can't really use the User model in the `Organization` model.

I also tried to reverse the `get_users_count` like `return self.user_set.count()` but that didn't work either.

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/project/accounts/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from project.organizations.models import Organization
  File "/Users/Manos/Projects/devboard/project/organizations/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from project.accounts.models import User
ImportError: cannot import name User
```

**Organization Model**

```
from uuidfield import UUIDField
from django.db import models
from project.accounts.models import User

class Organization(models.Model):

    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, auto=True, db_index=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_users_count(self):
        return User.objects.filter(organization=self).count()
```

**User Model**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # custom User models must have an integer PK
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, related_name="users", null=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the import into the `get_users_count()` method:

```
def get_users_count(self):
    from project.accounts.models import User
    return User.objects.filter(organization=self).count()
```

Or remove the import at all and use the backward relation:

```
def get_users_count(self):
    return self.users.count()
```

Comment: Tried both and both seem to work! I will use the first one since I don't really like the import inside the method. Since it's a foreign key, any idea why `self.user_set.count()` is not valid?

Comment: You set the `related_name="users"` in the foreign key definition.  This is why you need to use the `self.users` instead of `self.user_set`.

Comment: Oh so if there was no `related_name` then it would be `self.user_set`? Right?

Comment: Yep. Explanation is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: For first answer I think is better use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model